# Make a file open in browser instead of downloading it using CHROME & FireBox

Tags: c#

I tried to get a pdf file opened in chrome but it seems to be stuck in the middle of somewhere during displaying process. please assist

[image]

[Screen shot of Request and Result Headers being sent by application serving the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQVv3.jpg)

MyController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = ROLE_VIEW)]
    public void GetViewFiles(string attachmentID)
    {
        AttachmentBO bo = new AttachmentBO(this.CurrentUser);
        bo.GetViewFileData(attachmentID);

    }
```

AttachmentBO.cs:

```
   public void GetViewFileData(string attachmentID)
    {

        List<DownloadFileInfoViewModel> retDownloadFilesInfo = new List<DownloadFileInfoViewModel>();
        using (var context = this.GetContext())
        {
            retDownloadFilesInfo = context.GetfileData(attachmentID);
        }   

        // Clear the content of the response
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear(); 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;         
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + retDownloadFilesInfo[0].FileName);         
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", retDownloadFilesInfo[0].FileSize.ToString());          
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(retDownloadFilesInfo[0].FileExt.ToLower());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(retDownloadFilesInfo[0].FileData);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // this make stream and without it open 
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();                  
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: what type of file is it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered just using a simple `FileResult`.

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetPdf()
{
    var file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/sample.pdf"));
    Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", $"inline; filename={file.Name}");

    /* Return the file from a path
    return File(file.FullName, "application/pdf");
    */

    //return the file as binary contents
    var contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
    return File(contents, "application/pdf");

}
```

Now the key with the `FileResult` is to NOT set the filename (3rd optional parameter) as that will set duplicate `Content-Disposition` headers. This will result in the PDF displayed in browsers that support PDF viewing.

The above method has been tested in the following browsers.

1. Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115
2. Firefox 54.0.1
3. Internet Explorer 11
4. Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Your headers to make the PDF display inline the browser look correct, but you will also need to make sure the MIME Type is being sent as "application/pdf"

It could also be a user setting in the browser, please test if Chrome opens this [test PDF](http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) for you in the browser.

[Open PDFs in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en)

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More More and    then **Settings**.
- At the bottom, click **Advanced**.
- Under "Privacy  and security," click **Content settings**.
- Near the bottom, click    **PDF documents**.
- Turn off **Open PDFs using a different application**.

Chrome will now open PDFs automatically when you click them.

I have also seen weird behavior when the file name contains any non-numeric characters.

Try cleaning your file name:

```
public void GetViewFileData(string attachmentID)
{

    List<DownloadFileInfoViewModel> retDownloadFilesInfo = new List<DownloadFileInfoViewModel>();
    using (var context = this.GetContext())
    {
        retDownloadFilesInfo = context.GetfileData(attachmentID);
    }   

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    // Clear the content of the response
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear(); 
    response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    string filename = retDownloadFilesInfo[0].FileName;
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    filename = new string(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename).Where(ch => char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch)).ToArray()) + ext;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);        
    response.BinaryWrite(retDownloadFilesInfo[0].FileData);
    response.Flush(); // this make stream and without it open 
    response.End();
}
```

Comment: Open PDFs using a different application option is already turned off but still its not working.

Comment: Did you check the correct mime type was being sent?

Comment: If it is then it is a chrome setting or plugin that is forcing the download.

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot of the request/response headers from developer console (F12 - Network) to your question.

Comment: Also, put the content type first. Remove the content length header, it will get set automatically. And there is no need to buffer the response.

Comment: Added the screenshot, please check

Comment: I see you have a space in your file name which can cause problems. You tried without the file name and have the same issue? Does the code I posted work, please try it line for line.

Comment: I also added a test pdf. Can you confirm that it opens in chrome for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `;filename` section of the value for `Content-Disposition` is making it treat it like a download. Just set it to `Content-Disposition: inline` and it should behave as you wish. Having a filename implies that it's an attachment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: tried the same and still its not working, please assist.

Comment: As a quick comment omitting the name will set the pdf filename to the path (ie `GetViewFiles.pdf`), setting the name will ensure the correct name is downloaded. Also `When used in combination with Content-Disposition: attachment, it is used as the default filename for an eventual 'Save As" dialog presented to the user.` this does not mean it is an attachment however used to define the filename for the save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult GetFile(string path)
    {
        VerifyAccessOrThrow(path);

        var fileName = "example";
        //We need to enclose the filename in double quotes for the mighty Firefox
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename=\"{fileName}\"");
        Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
        return File(fileContent, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
    }
```

Comment: mayu, good work one thing is the `Response.ContentType` is set by the `FileResult`. The `contentType` field is required, ommiting it will cause an `ArgumentException`. So the `Response.ContentType` is not required, although has no negative imapact.